# Why don't mouseover or mouseout events fire from tests?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, qunit

I have the following QUnit test:

```
test 'can view saved status and undo if needed', ->
    save_link = $('.save-link')
    my_profile_div = $('.searchbar .span5')
    undo_save = $('#undo-save')

    my_profile_div.mouseover()
    equal(undo_save.css('visibility'), 'hidden')
    my_profile_div.mouseout()

    save_link.click()

    my_profile_div.mouseover()
    equal(undo_save.css('visibility'), 'visible')   
    my_profile_div.mouseout()
    equal(undo_save.css('visibility'), 'hidden')
```

It clicks a link, then expects some hover behavior to be present for the element `my_profile_div`. Unfortunately, the mouseover and mouseout events don't fire from the tests. I get no alerts when using this implementation:

```
$('.searchbar .span5').mouseover -> 
    alert('mouseover')

$('.searchbar .span5').mouseout -> 
    alert('mouseout')
```

In the browser I do get the alerts, but not when I run the test above, which makes me think I'm not triggering the events properly. I also tried `trigger('mouseover')` to no avail.

Thanks for taking the time to read this, guys. I appreciate your help greatly.

*NOTE:* The test is for the desired behavior. The implementation is just to make sure the test is doing what it's supposed to.

Answer (score -1):

I would rather use trigger to fire an event.

```
$('targetElement').trigger('eventName');
```

Comment: Okay what is your actual error you are getting? Another thing. I take it your test code is inside a function which is called after $(document).ready or a button click?

Comment: I'm not getting an error. As you can see, if the mouseover/mouseout events fire, you'd have to see two alerts, which doesn't happen when I run my tests, but does happen when I load the script into a webpage.

I'm using QUnit, so the test code is a webpage and tests are triggered from within a <script> tag